# what algorithm is used to pow() function in c

Tags: c, floating-point

> ```
> #include<stdio.h>
> #include<math.h>
>
> int main() {
> double n,p,ans;
> while(scanf("%lf %lf",&n,&p)==2)
> {
>     ans=pow(p,(1/n));
>
>     printf("%.0lf\n",ans);
> }
> return 0; 
>  }
> ```

what algorithm is used to find ans here.what is the complexity of this pow() function?.

Comment: It probably depends on the math library implementation - there's no guarantee that what the GNU math library uses is the same as the Microsoft compiler, or Intel, etc.

Comment: i guarantee that it is not my homework.

Comment: Just look on math.h implementation. If you want to learn something try to read code not about it.

Answer (score 7):

Section 4.12.7.4 of the C99 standard has nothing more to say about the `pow` functions than the following:

> **Synopsys**
>
> ```
> #include <math.h>
> double pow(double x, double y);
> float powf(float x, float y);
> long double powl(long double x, long double y);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> The `pow` functions compute `x` raised to the power `y`. A domain error occurs if `x` is ﬁnite and negative and `y` is ﬁnite and not an integer value. A range error may occur. A domain error may occur if `x` is zero and `y` is zero. A domain error or range error may occur if `x` is zero and `y` is less than zero.
>
> **Returns**
>
> The `pow` functions return [`x` raised to the power `y`].

Note that no information is given about the complexity of the function, and that there are no expectations about the algorithm to be used. This is because the functions could be native to the processor in some implementations of C, while on other architectures, floating-point processing isn't provided by hardware.

You can assume, though, that the complexity is not worse than that of `log`, multiplication and `exp` combined:

```
double pow(double x, double y) {
    return exp(log(x)*y);
}
```

On many platforms with an FP unit, base-e exponentiation, floating-point multiplication, and natural logarithms all take `O(1)` time, so `pow` should too.

-edit2- I'm not so sure anymore about the complexities for `exp` and `log`, but I think implementations use Taylor approximation and a bunch of lookup tables. That would still give `O(1)`.

Comment: but exp(log(x)*y) can not be calculated with O(1) time because log(x) should be multiplied y times;

Comment: FP multiplication should be `O(1)` on many architectures with an FP unit. In those cases, multiplication is implemented in hardware and takes a constant number of cycles. Keep in mind, this isn't an *exact* integer computation, but an *approximate* floating-point computation.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to say, as the previous answer says.

On x86, you could implement it using `fyl2x` which calculates (y *log2(x)), and the `f2xm1` instructions [along with a +1.0]

```
fld1            1.0
fld             y
fld             x 
fyl2x                  // y * log2(x)
fadd                   // add 1.0
f2xm1                  // 2 ^ (x-1)
```

Then on a processor with no or little support for exp/log instructions in the floating point unit, the log and exp would probably be calcualted using a seeries equation that could take 5-20 iterations depending on input values and how good the equation is.

I think the complexity still counts for O(1) in that case, but I'm sure we could come up with scenarios where it wouldn't work like that.

Comment: `pow` is generally not implemented with an iterative algorithm. Most commercial libraries use prepared minimax polynomials, along with other specialized techniques. The polynomial may have a number of terms, but probably not nearly so many as 20. One notable library, `crlibm`, may use a variable number of “iterations” in the sense that, in some of its function implementations, it does one evaluation, performs a test, and then does a more extensive evaluation if necessary. As I recall, I saw this for some of the simpler functions. I do not know that `crlibm` has conquered `pow` yet.

Comment: Yes, but that actually assumes the people writing the library actually knew what they were doing - and whilst I'm sure nearly all commercial libraries are either copies of something good, or something originally good, there is no guarantee in the C-library specification that this is the case. And my point is rather that it's a "you can't say unless you look at the source for the particular library used in a particular case".

Comment: With common C/C++ toolchains, pow(double,int) is often computed by iteration, as a look at relevant header files reveals. For pow(double, double) the usual approach is via variants of logarithm plus exponentiation (without iteration) with core approximations provided by minimax polynomials. The degree of those polynomials is largely a function of how the argument reduction is performed; there is a tradeoff between the size of tables used in that and the complexity of the polynomials. People who write math libraries professionally (all fifty or so :-) usually know very well what they are doing.